# web3: getPastEvents works in Truffle on instance, not in web3 script on page

Tags: web3js, truffle

I am looking to collect the previously logged events of a certain type using getPastEvents. It does not seem to work in my web3 script on my site but it does work in truffle console on a deployed instance. I am using this code:

```
myContract.getPastEvents('depositTx', {
      fromBlock: 0,
      toBlock: 'latest'
    }, function(error, result) {
      if (!error) {
        console.log(result);
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }
});
```

When I create a myContract instance in truffle console it works (e.g. let myContract = await contractName.deployed()) but when I try to run this on my web3 script where I have set the contract using address and ABI it does not (other method calls work fine).

Any thoughts?